# Activity lifecycle callbacks no fininshing execution?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

Is it possible that activity lifecycle callbacks get interrupted before executting all its code? can a callback interrupt another?

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

In this documentation it recommends not implementing heavy work in onPause for example as it has a "very brief execution", who controls that? how? does the system calls the next lifecycle callback even if onPause did not finish execution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Docs suggest that `onResume()/onPause()` execute rapidly for better user experience, because these methods are called frequently. Android activity callbacks are always executed in a sequence. They may be interrupted only by an uncaught exception which will terminate the whole app.

Answer (score 0):

Those calls are what will influence UI mostly (along with onCreate, onCreateView) and if they take a long time to complete their code the user will most certainly know about it.

Say you have this in your onResume() method

```
OnResume(){ super.onResume; updateView(); }
```

Something standard, this is what normally happens before the fragment or activity gets “resumed”.

If your updateView(); required 2seconds to complete, weather it’s loading data or creating objects, that’s 2 seconds that the UI is “frozen” and the user cannot use the app, or could mistake as “is broken”

If you have the theoretical same scenario for onPause() then that too is 2 seconds of “frozen” time in the app

It is preferred to have the “updateView()” (essentially your onResume and onPause methods) complete as quickly as possible so that the user does not notice any “lag” in the application.

Comment: so it's just a performance consideration? there is no way ever that one of these callbacks gets interrupted before it fully completes execution of its code? what i mean is that these methods are just callbacks that are triggered by another events, isn't it possible that this events happen in fast succession that a new callback occurs before the previous one completes execution? and in that case what would happen? would the new event callback wait in line until the previous callback finishes or it will interrupts it?

Comment: I would say the only way it doesn’t complete the full block of code would be fatal Exception error causing the application itself to crash and close. But even if it didn’t it would cause an “out of context” error of some type (not entirely sure what to call it), so any calculations on that call would be fine, but it would throw errors if you tried say getActivity().finish() because getActivity() would return null as it’s been GC’ed